TLS Handshake is happening twice when connecting to Oracle Database using JDBC Thin client
I have a simple JDBC program that is connecting to Oracle Database using TLSV1.2 but the database connection is taking around 2 second. After taking SSL dump it was observed TLS handshake is happening twice. Any pointers to overcome SSL Handshake twice.
Code:
package org.example;

import java.sql.*;

public class LocalTLSOracleDBExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        // Load the Oracle JDBC driver
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not load the driver");

        }

        //Create a connection
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=2484))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xe)))", "***", "***");
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time taken to establish TLS connection: " + (endTime - startTime) + "ms");

        // Get the JDBC driver name and version
        DatabaseMetaData dbmd = connection.getMetaData();
        System.out.println("Driver Name: " + dbmd.getDriverName());
        System.out.println("Driver Version: " + dbmd.getDriverVersion());
        System.out.println("JDBC Version:" + connection.getMetaData().getJDBCMajorVersion() + "." + connection.getMetaData().getJDBCMinorVersion());


        // Create a statement
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time taken to create statement: " + (endTime - startTime) + "ms");

        // Execute a query
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select count(SID) as counts from V$SESSION");
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time taken to execute query: " + (endTime - startTime) + "ms");

        // Process the result set
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            System.out.println("Data: " + resultSet.getString("counts"));
        }
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time taken to process result set: " + (endTime - startTime) + "ms");

        // Close the connection
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        connection.close();
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time taken to close connection: " + (endTime - startTime) + "ms");

    }


}

Logs
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.212 PDT|SSLCipher.java:438|jdk.tls.keyLimits:  entry = AES/GCM/NoPadding KeyUpdate 2^37. AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.266 PDT|ServerNameExtension.java:261|Unable to indicate server name
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.266 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:259|Ignore, context unavailable extension: server_name
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.266 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:259|Ignore, context unavailable extension: status_request
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.274 PDT|SignatureScheme.java:297|Signature algorithm, ed25519, is not supported by the underlying providers
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.274 PDT|SignatureScheme.java:297|Signature algorithm, ed448, is not supported by the underlying providers
javax.net.ssl|INFO|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.277 PDT|AlpnExtension.java:178|No available application protocols
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.277 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:259|Ignore, context unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.277 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:259|Ignore, context unavailable extension: status_request_v2
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.277 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:259|Ignore, context unavailable extension: cookie`
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.289 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:259|Ignore, context unavailable extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.290 PDT|PreSharedKeyExtension.java:632|No session to resume.
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.290 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:259|Ignore, context unavailable extension: pre_shared_key
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.291 PDT|ClientHello.java:556|Produced ClientHello handshake message (
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "04 D2 57 1A 5A F9 6D F0 E3 6A D3 A7 33 E3 99 35 ED 53 82 03 3D 26 E2 75 09 0E 2D 73 C0 95 D4 01",
  "session id"          : "47 58 D8 82 D5 FE D6 70 C7 00 6D BE B7 1D CE 42 79 50 67 5A B8 F0 E0 51 A9 B8 0F 8B 0C A7 DF 28",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x1302), TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x1301), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02C), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02B), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02F), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009F), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x00A3), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009E), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x00A2), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC024), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC028), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC023), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC027), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006B), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006A), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0067), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0040), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02E), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC032), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02D), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC031), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC026), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC02A), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC025), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC029), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00A), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC014), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC009), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC013), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0039), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0038), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0033), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0032), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC005), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00F), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC004), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC00E), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009D), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009C), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x003D), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x003C), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0035), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x002F), TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV(0x00FF)]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "supported_groups (10)": {
      "versions": [secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192]
    },
    "ec_point_formats (11)": {
      "formats": [uncompressed]
    },
    "signature_algorithms (13)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "signature_algorithms_cert (50)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "extended_master_secret (23)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "versions": [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2]
    },
    "psk_key_exchange_modes (45)": {
      "ke_modes": [psk_dhe_ke]
    },
    "key_share (51)": {
      "client_shares": [  
        {
          "named group": secp256r1
          "key_exchange": {
            0000: 04 39 4E 8A 19 4D D1 9D   FE A0 D7 B0 F0 C5 9F 57  .9N..M.........W
            0010: AD CB B6 68 74 63 56 65   67 AF 93 F0 32 A2 42 E1  ...htcVeg...2.B.
            0020: A7 F6 EA 5A 84 F0 36 D4   CA B3 1B FB 47 D6 F8 6E  ...Z..6.....G..n
            0030: 37 4F A1 F1 08 BD 2E 43   39 CF 88 14 65 1F B0 ED  7O.....C9...e...
            0040: 06 
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.297 PDT|ServerHello.java:862|Consuming ServerHello handshake message (
"ServerHello": {
  "server version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "66 62 2D 44 D8 99 48 5A B3 02 D7 F3 B1 52 13 8D 97 F3 5F 54 9B 3B D3 E7 85 EF 9D 4F D6 43 E9 33",
  "session id"          : "53 5F BC 4D 6D BD AD 20 7F 93 55 7D 3E F7 6D 5A 1A 00 CD 98 86 C3 86 6F 11 2C 51 1C D5 80 5F 9D",
  "cipher suite"        : "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030)",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "renegotiation_info (65,281)": {
      "renegotiated connection": [<no renegotiated connection>]
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.297 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:172|Ignore unavailable extension: supported_versions
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.297 PDT|ServerHello.java:953|Negotiated protocol version: TLSv1.2
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.298 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:191|Consumed extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.298 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:172|Ignore unavailable extension: server_name
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.298 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:172|Ignore unavailable extension: max_fragment_length
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.298 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:172|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.298 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:172|Ignore unavailable extension: ec_point_formats
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.298 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:172|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request_v2
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.298 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:162|Ignore unsupported extension: supported_versions
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.298 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:162|Ignore unsupported extension: key_share
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.299 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:191|Consumed extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.299 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:162|Ignore unsupported extension: pre_shared_key
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.299 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:206|Ignore unavailable extension: server_name
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.299 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:206|Ignore unavailable extension: max_fragment_length
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.299 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:206|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.299 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:206|Ignore unavailable extension: ec_point_formats
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.299 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:206|Ignore unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.299 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:206|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request_v2
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.299 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:206|Ignore unavailable extension: extended_master_secret
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.299 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:206|Ignore unavailable extension: supported_versions
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.299 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:206|Ignore unavailable extension: key_share
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.299 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:214|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.299 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:206|Ignore unavailable extension: pre_shared_key
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.300 PDT|CertificateMessage.java:364|Consuming server Certificate handshake message (
"Certificates": [
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v1",
    "serial number"      : "00 8E E0 2A 96 10 CA 4B 41 50 DC 74 63 0C 99 04 AE",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "CN=localhost",
    "not before"         : "2024-06-04 15:36:35.000 PDT",
    "not  after"         : "2025-06-04 15:36:35.000 PDT",
    "subject"            : "CN=localhost",
    "subject public key" : "RSA"}
]
)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.306 PDT|ECDHServerKeyExchange.java:531|Consuming ECDH ServerKeyExchange handshake message (
"ECDH ServerKeyExchange": {
  "parameters": {
    "named group": "secp256r1"
    "ecdh public": {
      0000: 04 BD DF CB 08 E3 56 D3   66 CB 85 4A 5B 47 53 B1  ......V.f..J[GS.
      0010: E5 E4 E8 B2 D4 23 08 72   28 FE 97 88 32 9B 2F AB  .....#.r(...2./.
      0020: E4 55 0F 5A DB D5 5D 79   BA 24 CD 9F DA C4 1B 20  .U.Z..]y.$..... 
      0030: 99 47 20 2A A8 0F 43 AC   9B 16 D2 B2 4B 42 36 C9  .G *..C.....KB6.
      0040: F9                                                 .
    },
  },
  "digital signature":  {
    "signature algorithm": "rsa_pkcs1_sha384"
    "signature": {
      0000: 3B DE 81 BE B7 4F E8 80   29 65 F4 F1 06 AE 1F 90  ;....O..)e......
      0010: D6 05 67 12 6F EB 5A F5   53 D0 BF 4B 6A 06 F8 2B  ..g.o.Z.S..Kj..+
      0020: C0 83 12 4D E0 6D F6 B8   69 B1 77 3B EE 1E F6 FC  ...M.m..i.w;....
      0030: 95 5E 14 0A 8F ED 11 2E   4A D2 75 FA AA 0C EF E0  .^......J.u.....
      0040: B6 06 E8 0A AD 22 76 1E   CF 8D 5C 18 5E 40 F6 A0  ....."v...\.^@..
      0050: 58 0B 01 2E 9D 5A EF 1C   CD ED 0D 34 24 BF BE FD  X....Z.....4$...
      0060: 6E 1D 4C 46 FA 6B 68 73   E8 29 D0 5D CA E3 7E 82  n.LF.khs.).]....
      0070: 8A D3 50 B0 46 CF DF 88   A9 B8 CB CA 98 58 B0 BA  ..P.F........X..
      0080: 6C 2F 60 08 B3 9E E5 F3   0E 96 53 64 FC C8 EE ED  l/`.......Sd....
      0090: D7 CF F6 BC 85 70 49 2A   D8 58 0B DC 72 B6 4C 32  .....pI*.X..r.L2
      00A0: 6B F3 00 9E 76 F4 85 F7   D0 BC 66 E8 EA 2D 4D 9B  k...v.....f..-M.
      00B0: D9 CC 24 A4 97 75 D8 85   66 03 2D D5 AA 50 F1 85  ..$..u..f.-..P..
      00C0: D6 51 A8 27 4D 77 5C E0   F3 4E 56 51 D2 4A 3B 5E  .Q.'Mw\..NVQ.J;^
      00D0: CE 3A 2F 9E 10 92 4A CF   17 BD 04 69 DE 47 42 2D  .:/...J....i.GB-
      00E0: 46 38 52 A9 66 B3 B3 74   A0 D1 B6 79 05 B3 19 90  F8R.f..t...y....
      00F0: C8 96 B3 86 77 4D DD EC   7A 56 A3 C6 E4 AB A3 58  ....wM..zV.....X
    },
  }
}
)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.307 PDT|ServerHelloDone.java:151|Consuming ServerHelloDone handshake message (
<empty>
)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.310 PDT|ECDHClientKeyExchange.java:396|Produced ECDHE ClientKeyExchange handshake message (
"ECDH ClientKeyExchange": {
  "ecdh public": {
    0000: 04 8D 6F 91 F7 3F 4F 9C   1B 1F 43 49 58 48 E1 EF  ..o..?O...CIXH..
    0010: 73 43 F4 18 D1 F9 13 C1   AE 1B 14 68 CF 64 57 D9  sC.........h.dW.
    0020: 86 A9 BF 6E 01 A1 78 25   D4 08 D1 9B 43 1F 45 20  ...n..x%....C.E 
    0030: 28 D3 D4 DB E9 A3 DB 21   BB 34 28 3D B2 15 04 1C  (......!.4(=....
    0040: C1                                                 .
  },
}
)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.317 PDT|ChangeCipherSpec.java:115|Produced ChangeCipherSpec message
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.317 PDT|Finished.java:393|Produced client Finished handshake message (
"Finished": {
  "verify data": {
    0000: E3 67 DC E2 C5 41 76 94   98 5E 40 CB 
  }'}
)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.331 PDT|ChangeCipherSpec.java:149|Consuming ChangeCipherSpec message
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.333 PDT|Finished.java:521|Consuming server Finished handshake message (
"Finished": {
  "verify data": {
    0000: 1A 73 B5 C4 20 69 A3 BC   2F E5 85 EB 
  }'}
)
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.357 PDT|ServerNameExtension.java:261|Unable to indicate server name
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.357 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:259|Ignore, context unavailable extension: server_name
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.357 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:259|Ignore, context unavailable extension: status_request
javax.net.ssl|INFO|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.358 PDT|AlpnExtension.java:178|No available application protocols
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.358 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:259|Ignore, context unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.358 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:259|Ignore, context unavailable extension: status_request_v2
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.358 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:259|Ignore, context unavailable extension: cookie
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.359 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:259|Ignore, context unavailable extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.360 PDT|PreSharedKeyExtension.java:632|No session to resume.
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.360 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:259|Ignore, context unavailable extension: pre_shared_key
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.360 PDT|ClientHello.java:556|Produced ClientHello handshake message (
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "5F 1F 4B 28 45 28 F8 7D 72 CB 57 9A 49 1A 92 28 C6 53 43 AD 5C D4 0B 95 07 1B 0B 78 92 A0 07 1D",
  "session id"          : "84 97 B3 C0 F1 8A 97 3D F7 33 8F 5A 8A EF 68 AE 29 7C 7E F3 F2 07 98 91 DA 81 5E C6 93 8B 42 B0",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x1302), TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x1301), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02C), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02B), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02F), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009F), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x00A3), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009E), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x00A2), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC024), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC028), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC023), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC027), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006B), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006A), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0067), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0040), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02E), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC032), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02D), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC031), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC026), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC02A), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC025), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC029), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00A), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC014), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC009), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC013), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0039), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0038), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0033), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0032), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC005), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00F), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC004), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC00E), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009D), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009C), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x003D), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x003C), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0035), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x002F), TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV(0x00FF)]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "supported_groups (10)": {
      "versions": [secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192]
    },
    "ec_point_formats (11)": {
      "formats": [uncompressed]
    },
    "signature_algorithms (13)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "signature_algorithms_cert (50)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "extended_master_secret (23)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "versions": [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2]
    },
    "psk_key_exchange_modes (45)": {
      "ke_modes": [psk_dhe_ke]
    },
    "key_share (51)": {
      "client_shares": [  
        {
          "named group": secp256r1
          "key_exchange": {
            0000: 04 CB 2A AF 7B 69 43 21   83 A4 9C 59 55 E3 7B 1E  ..*..iC!...YU...
            0010: 55 93 57 61 4E 1A AB 3B   77 9B 9C 71 ED 33 35 C8  U.WaN..;w..q.35.
            0020: 40 46 96 99 21 4C 8C 32   3D EA A3 8D 4A 44 0A E9  @F..!L.2=...JD..
            0030: 58 52 81 BB 54 A9 BC 38   F1 72 75 4D C9 95 04 66  XR..T..8.ruM...f
            0040: 9A 
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.362 PDT|ServerHello.java:862|Consuming ServerHello handshake message (
"ServerHello": {
  "server version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "66 62 2D 44 2C CD 65 94 04 F9 64 B6 2E 02 43 78 1A 54 58 8F C1 18 D2 CB 68 0E DB A7 2B 47 05 EA",
  "session id"          : "7C E1 BF E7 7B 30 1F D8 BF A0 B6 D2 DD 19 38 06 09 2C 5E 49 26 ED DD A9 E3 20 21 55 B4 AE FC 12",
  "cipher suite"        : "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030)",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "renegotiation_info (65,281)": {
      "renegotiated connection": [<no renegotiated connection>]
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.362 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:172|Ignore unavailable extension: supported_versions
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.362 PDT|ServerHello.java:953|Negotiated protocol version: TLSv1.2
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.362 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:191|Consumed extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.363 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:172|Ignore unavailable extension: server_name
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.363 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:172|Ignore unavailable extension: max_fragment_length
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.363 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:172|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.363 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:172|Ignore unavailable extension: ec_point_formats
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.363 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:172|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request_v2
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.363 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:162|Ignore unsupported extension: supported_versions
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.363 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:162|Ignore unsupported extension: key_share
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.363 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:191|Consumed extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.363 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:162|Ignore unsupported extension: pre_shared_key
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.363 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:206|Ignore unavailable extension: server_name
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.364 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:206|Ignore unavailable extension: max_fragment_length
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.364 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:206|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.364 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:206|Ignore unavailable extension: ec_point_formats
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.364 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:206|Ignore unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.364 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:206|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request_v2
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.364 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:206|Ignore unavailable extension: extended_master_secret
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.364 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:206|Ignore unavailable extension: supported_versions
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.364 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:206|Ignore unavailable extension: key_share
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.364 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:214|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.364 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:206|Ignore unavailable extension: pre_shared_key
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.364 PDT|CertificateMessage.java:364|Consuming server Certificate handshake message (
"Certificates": [
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v1",
    "serial number"      : "00 8E E0 2A 96 10 CA 4B 41 50 DC 74 63 0C 99 04 AE",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "CN=localhost",
    "not before"         : "2024-06-04 15:36:35.000 PDT",
    "not  after"         : "2025-06-04 15:36:35.000 PDT",
    "subject"            : "CN=localhost",
    "subject public key" : "RSA"}
]
)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.365 PDT|ECDHServerKeyExchange.java:531|Consuming ECDH ServerKeyExchange handshake message (
"ECDH ServerKeyExchange": {
  "parameters": {
    "named group": "secp256r1"
    "ecdh public": {
      0000: 04 AC 7F BA 30 7E 65 6E   02 80 61 5E E7 54 42 36  ....0.en..a^.TB6
      0010: 0C 52 93 95 D6 BE 49 4E   A2 11 4E 86 29 48 4F AD  .R....IN..N.)HO.
      0020: 64 9B 47 34 E1 B7 D5 79   61 C2 BD 40 6A F3 34 C5  d.G4...ya..@j.4.
      0030: 0E AC 37 55 47 5E 07 B9   BF AD 3C 7A 8A 5E D4 26  ..7UG^....<z.^.&
      0040: C8                                                 .
    },
  },
  "digital signature":  {
    "signature algorithm": "rsa_pkcs1_sha384"
    "signature": {
      0000: 17 BD 93 EB C2 38 72 8A   82 A9 4D DD 33 DD 64 40  .....8r...M.3.d@
      0010: 0E 20 48 39 F1 59 4E AF   39 2C E7 A7 E9 8F 16 96  . H9.YN.9,......
      0020: 7E 2E DC AA 98 94 FF 03   6D 14 B8 A2 40 50 42 5D  ........m...@PB]
      0030: DB FF 44 BC 3F 8B 5E FF   CD 3A 36 86 14 63 77 1D  ..D.?.^..:6..cw.
      0040: 5E 25 A2 7C D0 DA 9E 47   D8 8E E1 96 6C 8D A6 6F  ^%.....G....l..o
      0050: A1 12 0C B9 17 5A DC A5   5C 29 87 C5 C0 CF 9D 70  .....Z..\).....p
      0060: 18 17 69 57 6E 6D F5 A2   4F DC 9D 7F 20 83 3A 23  ..iWnm..O... .:#
      0070: 4F F5 66 85 C6 58 AF C1   58 CF 5A BF 07 9D C1 1F  O.f..X..X.Z.....
      0080: 37 C8 B7 5D ED 32 FA 59   8A 70 FE 96 48 9E 6E 4A  7..].2.Y.p..H.nJ
      0090: 87 57 F2 1F EC 5A C0 59   F2 E9 1A A8 FB 2C EB 69  .W...Z.Y.....,.i
      00A0: 41 60 AB FD C8 20 C6 5B   5B 2E DF 38 84 B8 3F 98  A`... .[[..8..?.
      00B0: FB 8C D5 11 F9 BB 9D 61   6B E4 8C C4 EA 1E 50 EF  .......ak.....P.
      00C0: 74 FD 6C 88 54 38 F2 75   D3 20 BD 10 63 5C 30 CC  t.l.T8.u. ..c\0.
      00D0: 7C 86 D2 45 8D 27 63 43   44 6D 91 DE 63 8D 6D 5C  ...E.'cCDm..c.m\
      00E0: FC 8F 71 13 83 35 25 87   E7 63 AD EC 63 BF 1F B8  ..q..5%..c..c...
      00F0: 44 AB F6 77 0C FA 07 69   8A 46 D5 A5 B1 16 3E 92  D..w...i.F....>.
    },
  }
}
)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.365 PDT|ServerHelloDone.java:151|Consuming ServerHelloDone handshake message (
<empty>
)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.366 PDT|ECDHClientKeyExchange.java:396|Produced ECDHE ClientKeyExchange handshake message (
"ECDH ClientKeyExchange": {
  "ecdh public": {
    0000: 04 FE 49 1F DE 28 C5 EF   59 72 F5 06 F5 9B 99 C2  ..I..(..Yr......
    0010: A0 41 F4 B2 2E F7 06 D7   E6 D0 AC 4C 75 5E 64 CB  .A.........Lu^d.
    0020: 13 42 8C ED 8B 1C 21 ED   CA 58 91 D0 D7 1E A8 DF  .B....!..X......
    0030: 51 97 70 8E CF F4 D9 97   2C 22 A0 67 EF AA FB 01  Q.p.....,".g....
    0040: 79                                                 y
  },
}
)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.369 PDT|ChangeCipherSpec.java:115|Produced ChangeCipherSpec message
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.369 PDT|Finished.java:393|Produced client Finished handshake message (
"Finished": {
  "verify data": {
    0000: 7B BE FC 8E 43 F7 04 FD   42 D2 19 B3 
  }'}
)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.370 PDT|ChangeCipherSpec.java:149|Consuming ChangeCipherSpec message
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-06-06 14:42:28.371 PDT|Finished.java:521|Consuming server Finished handshake message (
"Finished": {
  "verify data": {
    0000: 9D 2E 62 CB 03 CB B1 2A   47 84 39 9E 
  }'}
)
Time taken to establish TLS connection: 1846ms
Driver Name: Oracle JDBC driver
Driver Version: 23.4.0.24.05
JDBC Version:4.2
Time taken to create statement: 75ms
Time taken to execute query: 41ms
Data: 88
Time taken to process result set: 3ms
Time taken to close connection: 5ms



TLS connection is taking 2 seconds. Trying to find options to reduce connection time.

Recently we contacted Oracle JDBC Thin driver development team and they confirmed the  Twice TLS  handshake is by design and there are no plans this juncture to reduce it to one.
